# Python Mutagen tag KeyError, how to pass when tag does not exists

Tags: python, mutagen

In Mutagen i read tags form an audiofile but when the tag don't exist, i get an error of course.

```
audio = ID3(musicfile)
print(audio['TXXX:SERIES'].text[0])

KeyError: 'TXXX:SERIES'
```

how to move on if tag don't exist?

i have tried:

```
 if audio['TXXX:SERIES'].text[0] is None:
        print('No series')
    else:
```

also

```
if not audio['TXXX:SERIES'].text[0]:
            print('No series')
        else:
```

still gives an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\xxxxx\all_the_program.py", line 163, in <module>
    if audio['TXXX:SERIES'].text[0] is None:
  File "D:\xxxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 537, in __getitem__
    return self.__dict[key]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\xxxxx\all_the_program.py", line 163, in <module>
    if not audio['TXXX:SERIES'].text[0]:
  File "D:\xxxxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 537, in __getitem__
    return self.__dict[key]
KeyError: 'TXXX:SERIES'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use try/except:

```
try:
    print(audio['TXXX:SERIES'].text[0])
except:
    print('An exception occurred')
```

And if you want that nothing happens when an exception occurs, just use pass:

```
try:
    print(audio['TXXX:SERIES'].text[0])
except:
    pass
```

You can learn more about catching exceptions / exceptions handling here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Thank you, such a basic thing and i forget.